# Resumable upload to GCS from Android client using `upload_id` for auth

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage

This is from the GCS Access Control documentation on [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) and it matches my use case exactly (the resumable upload scenario):

> Note: If your users are only uploading resources (writing) to an
>   access-controlled bucket, you can use the resumable uploads
>   functionality of Google Cloud Storage, and avoid signing URLs or
>   requiring a Google account. In a resumable upload scenario, your
>   (server-side) code authenticates and initiates an upload to Google
>   Cloud Storage without actually uploading any data. The initiation
>   request returns an upload ID, which can then be used in a client
>   request to upload the data. The client request does not need to be
>   signed because the upload ID, in effect, acts as an authentication
>   token. If you choose this path, be sure to transmit the upload ID over
>   HTTPS.

I have a GAE instance which successfully authenticates and initiates a resumable upload to GCS. As expected, GCS returns my GAE server a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/<my-apps-default-bucket>/o?uploadType=resumable&name=<my-file-name>&upload_id=xa298sd_sdlkj2
Content-Length: 0
```

The GAE server hands the Android client the URL from the above location and the Android client uses this to try to `PUT` the file to GCS. Here is the basic code snippet used:

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = <URL-returned in Location-Header>; // exactly the URL returned in the GCS response above
        Log.v("PUT URL", url);
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
        put.addHeader("Content-Type", "<my-file-mime-type>");
        // Note that HttpPut adds the `Content_Length` based on the entity added. Doing it by hand will throw an Exception

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("<path-to-my-file>"));

        HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
        put.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

        responseMsg = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.v("resultMsg", responseMsg);
```

Logs show the response from GCS for the above `PUT` is:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"badRequest",
            "message":"Invalid Upload Request"
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"Invalid Upload Request"
   }
}
```

My question is to anyone who has gotten the resumable upload scenario to work for this use case: (1) Client asks server to initiate resumable upload, (2) server initiates upload and gets `Location` with `upload_id`, (3) server passes these to client, (4) client uses these to upload file to GCS directly with no additional authentication (no signed URL). Is there something I'm missing? According to the documentation it looks like this approach should be working. Does anyone have pointers or experience that could help me out?

Thanks.